# Express/Node.js | Generating a new JSON object from within a glob call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, glob

I'm very new to JS and I think I'm missing something fundamental regarding the storage of an object state and the structure of nested function calls.

I'm globbing a directory containing many JSON files and I want to load these iteratively and parse the contents to a single JSON object. 
I'm parsing the contents correctly inside the function, but as I've written it, the object state isn't persisting outside the function.

```
const glob = require('glob');

const retrieve = (query) => {
    const dataJSON = {};
    const json_path = saveDir + '/upload/' + query + '/'
    glob(json_path + '*.json', function (er, files) {
        for (index in files) {
            dataJSON[index] = require(files[index])
        }
        // Logging here returns the correct object
        console.log(dataJSON)
        return dataJSON
    });
    // Logging here returns an empty object
    console.log(dataJSON)
    return dataJSON

}

// I need to return the object here
app.get('/patent', (req, res) => {
    res.json(retrieve(req.query['q']))
});
```

Two questions, how do I persist 'dataJSON' outside of glob, and how would I return 'files' from outside of glob?

Ex. for second question

```
var example = glob("**/*.js", function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.

  return files
})

console.log(example)
>>['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to iterate further on Tyler's answer, since you are new to JS. JavaScript relies heavily on callbacks or promises since its async. Meaning that the order you read the code isn't (always) the order the code gets executed.

Your code looks like this:

1. Define the function retrieve
2. Define some variables
3. Call glob to read some files
4. Do something with those files `//loggin here returns correct`
5. Return dataJSON results `//loggin here returns empty`

But it will be executed in the following order:

1. Define the function retrieve
2. Define some variables
3. Call glob to read some files
4. Return dataJSON results  `//loggin here returns empty`
5. Do something with those files `//loggin here returns correct`

The reason is that the glob call takes some times (nr 3 in the list). It's maybe just a few ms but your code continues to run. So while glob is reading those files your program still run. When glob has finished it runs the callback function.

The callback is basically "hey when you have read those files, then do this to them"

So when you do the console.log you haven't done anything to the files. Glob is still working.

You can see this with few console.logs.

```
const retrieve = (query) => {
    console.log('STEP 1')
    const dataJSON = {};
    const json_path = saveDir + '/upload/' + query + '/'
    glob(json_path + '*.json', function (er, files) {
        for (index in files) {
            dataJSON[index] = require(files[index])
        }
        // Logging here returns the correct object
        console.log('STEP 2')
        return dataJSON
    });
    console.log('STEP 3')
    // Logging here returns an empty object
    console.log(dataJSON)
    return dataJSON
}
```

So you would think the output would be:

```
STEP 1
STEP 2
STEP 3
```

but it will be:

```
STEP 1
STEP 3
STEP 2
```

There are a few ways like Tyler mentioned to fix this.

**You could continue with callbacks.**

```
const glob = require('glob');

const retrieve = (query, cb) => {
    const dataJSON = {};
    const json_path = saveDir + '/upload/' + query + '/'
    glob(json_path + '*.json', function (er, files) {
        for (index in files) {
            dataJSON[index] = require(files[index])
        }
        // Logging here returns the correct object
        console.log(dataJSON)
        cb(dataJSON)
    });
}

app.get('/patent', (req, res) => {
  retrieve(req.query['q'], function(resultsFromGlob) {
    res.json(resultsFromGlob) 
  })
});
```

Note that I add a new parameter to your retrieve function. That is the callback so that we know when glob has finished. Now I can use that callback in the router.

**The other way is to use promises.**

This is the method Tyler suggested and I agree. Personally I like promises more than callbacks.

```
const retrieve = (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      const dataJSON = {};
      const json_path = saveDir + '/upload/' + query + '/'
      glob(json_path + '*.json', function (er, files) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error)
          }

          for (index in files) {
              dataJSON[index] = require(files[index])
          }

          resolve(dataJSON);
      });
    })
}

app.get('/patent', (req, res) => {
  retrieve(req.query['q']).then(resultsFromGlob => {
    res.json(resultsFromGlob) 
  })  
});
```

This also gives me the option to use async/await

```
const retrieve = async (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      const dataJSON = {};
      const json_path = saveDir + '/upload/' + query + '/'
      glob(json_path + '*.json', function (er, files) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error)
          }

          for (index in files) {
              dataJSON[index] = require(files[index])
          }

          resolve(dataJSON);
      });
    })
}

app.get('/patent', async (req, res) => {
  const resultsFromGlob = await retrieve(req.query['q'])        
  res.json(resultsFromGlob) 
});
```

Comment: good answer - one thing I noticed from a quick read over is that you're missing the `async` keyword from your express handler in the last codeblock (you need it with when using `await` in the following context).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I see the issue now and have a much better understanding of asynchronous calls!

Answer (score 1):

`glob` looks to be asynchronous (hence the callback/`dataJson` being an empty object). You have two options:

**Promisify it**

```
function retrieve (query) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    glob(json_path + "*.json", function (err, files) {
      if (err) reject(files)
      else resolve(files)
    })
  })
}

app.get("/patent", (req, res) => {
  retrieve(req.query["q"])).then(files => res.json(files))
})
```

or just **inline it** and return your response in the callback

```
app.get("/patent", (req, res) => {
  glob(json_path + "*.json", function (err, files) {
    res.json(files)
  })
})
```